# Codeigniter csrf protection error in Javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, form-submit, internal-server-error, csrf-protection

I am using CSRF protection in CodeIgniter 2.2.1

I want to form submit process when I click datatable. Therefore, I create form element in javascript in click event. When form submit process run I get "500 Internal Server Error".

Here is my code for datatable click event;

```
var form = $('<form></form>', {
                    id: "tdClickForm",
                    name: "tdClickForm",
                    method: 'post',
                    action: "<?= base_url(); ?>files/folderClick"
                });

                var cellInput = document.createElement("input");
                cellInput.setAttribute("name", "currentCell");
                cellInput.setAttribute("value", 1);;

                form.append(cellInput);
                form.appendTo('body').submit();
```

Comment: if you have enabled csrf protection you need to post hash and token pair also

Answer (score 0):

```
var csrf_test_name = document.createElement("input");
                csrf_test_name .setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                csrf_test_name .setAttribute("name", "csrf_test_name");
                csrf_test_name .setAttribute("id", "csrf_test_name");
                csrf_test_name .setAttribute("value", $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name'));

form.append(csrf_test_name);
form.appendTo('body').submit();
```

this solve the problem.